Style material react tab to remove the bottom border
I am trying to style material tabs and I am able to do it by creating a theme and overriding the defaults like this
MuiTab: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      textTransform: 'capitalize', // Set textTransform to capitalize,
      fontWeight: 600,
      '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
        width: 72,
        height: 'auto',
        marginBottom: 6,
      },
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        borderTop: `2px solid ${COLORS.PrimaryMedDark}`,
        borderLeft: `1px solid ${COLORS.BorderGray}`,
        borderRight: `1px solid ${COLORS.BorderGray}`,
        borderBottom: 'none',
        color: COLORS.PrimaryMedDark,
        '.MuiAvatar-img': {
          //border: ' 2px solid #FFC44D !important',
        },
      },
      '& .MuiIconButton-root': {
        padding: 0,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.White,
      },
    },
  },
},

You can see I am able to add the left, right and top borders to the selected tab.

Everything is working except for the bottom border, I am not able to remove it by any way.
I found this solution to give tabs your custom design
https://mui.com/base-ui/react-tabs/
But this is too much to do, because for my case I am able to achieve everything I want in the styles except for the bottom border.
So is creating custom style component as mentioned in the link above the only way to achieve it or is there any way to make it work with the existing tabs?
Update
Tried to set the border bottom on '&.Mui-selected' to this borderBottom: '5px solid red',, and see the result

So basically this blue line is not the border on selected Tab element because the red border that I set on selected tab appears even above that default blue line. So this default blue border is somewhere else, may be at the parent and that is why it is not going away by the change in the style of the selected tab. Actually it appears with an animation when the tab is selected.

can you change borderBottomWidth?

@MarkSwardstrom - Tried to set the border bottom width to 0px, didn't work. Actually I tried one more thing with border, please check the update part in question

It may be the nav.component-tabs::before

You can try
outline: none !important; //important remove even if element focus

I am not sure that it will fix the problem for you.
Actually, the border will be created by outline or border, but sometimes will created by pseudo-element like ::after or ::before. Check all cases, please.
